# Sending a PHP request from first page to second using ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, instagram

I'm trying to set up my Instagram API site so that users can click on photos and "like" them.  I have a like.php to send this 'like' information to the API.  I'd like to be able to click on the image, send an ajax response calling like.php, having like.php do its thing and send back an "ok" if things went well.

I'm having a problem now even getting this ajax call to like.php running right.  Most of the time my page wont even load and will not give any error info in the console.

Here's my code:

on the image:

```
echo "<img src='like.jpg' class='like' onclick='likePic(".$picId.",".$userId.")'>"
```

the function in main.php

```
function likePic(picId, userId){

        $.get('path/to/like.php?picid=' + picId + '&userid=' + userId+ "&r=" + (new Date().getTime()), function(data) {
         if (data != "ok") {    
   }
  }
 }
```

and lastly, like.php

```
<?php

require 'instagram.class.php';


$instagram = new Instagram(array(

  'apiKey'      => '******************',
  'apiSecret'   => '******************',
  'apiCallback' => '*******************'

));


$token = userId;
$instagram->setAccessToken($token);
$id =  $_GET['pic'];
$instagram->likeMedia($id);


if ($result->meta->code === 200) {

  echo 'Success! The image was added to your likes.';

} else {

  echo 'Something went wrong';

}

?>
```

Comment: This looks suspect: `$token = ;`

Comment: @MikeW - I'm pretty sure that's censored sensitive information.  @BrandN00b - Your like.php page is returning `Success!` or `Something went wrong` but your main.php is expecting `ok`.

Comment: @GigaWatt So am I, but with the quality of some questions here anything is possible.

Comment: If you're using jQuery don't use inline JavaScript listeners.

Comment: Are you using something like Chrome Developer Tools to track your AJAX request and response?

Comment: @MikeW i fixed that.  My problem is I can't even get main.php to load. I'm using chrome tools, but I suspect to start, my AJAX isnt even being sent.

Comment: @diggersworld what would you suggest I use?

Comment: `$result` hasn't been initialized for the IF. Do you need `$result = $instagram->likeMedia($id);`?

Answer (score 2):

Front-end PHP/HTML/JS:

```
<img src="" alt="" data-pic-id="<?php echo $picId; ?>" data-user-id="<?php echo $userId; ?>">

<script>

    // listens for a click event on all <img> elements
    $('img').click(onImageClicked);

    // the function to handle the click event
    function onImageClicked() {
        var picId = $(this).attr('data-pic-id');
        var userId = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
        $.get('path/to/like.php?pic=' + picId + '&userid=' + userId+ "&r=" + (new Date().getTime()), function(data) {
            if (data != "ok") {    
                // failed
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

like.php:

```
<?php

    $id = (isset($_GET['pic'])) ? $_GET['pic'] : null;
    if ($id) 
    {
         // do instagram stuff
         // initialize $result;
    }

    if (empty($result) || $result->meta->code !== 200)
    {
        echo 'error';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ok';
    }
```

Notice in your example JS sends `picid` but PHP looks for `pic`.
It's probably better to put the `userId` elsewhere than on the photo, unless it will be different per photo.

Personally when responding to AJAX calls I prefer to use JSON but that's up to you.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Notice: Undefined variable: picId in /././main.php on line 168.  Also getting the same for userId

Answer (score 1):

In your main.php file, the response given is either `Success! The image was added to your likes.` or `Something went wrong`.
However, your `likePic` function is comparing the returned to the text `ok` which will never be true.

As for debugging your page load and AJAX issues, don't expect everything to magically show up in the console.  Sometimes it's best to include `console.log()` calls so you can see what code paths are actually being taken and what data is being passed around.

Lastly, it would be wise to check your PHP error log as well to ensure that all parts of your setup, including the back-end, are functioning as expected.

Comment: I havent gotten really to that point yet. Yes, you are correct but Im guessing i'm not even getting like.php called yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require 'instagram.class.php';


$instagram = new Instagram(array(

'apiKey'      => '******************',
'apiSecret'   => '******************',
'apiCallback' => '*******************'

));


$token = 'add your token'; // place a valid token here
$instagram->setAccessToken($token);
$id =  $_GET['pic'];
$instagram->likeMedia($id);


if ($result->meta->code === 200) {

    echo 'ok';

} else {

    echo 'Something went wrong';

}

?>
```

Now should work fine